# Clean code applying weights to Guava Table values

Tags: java, java-8, coding-style, guava, guava-table

I am transforming guava Table object, applying weights.

method input Type is below, where Row and Column are some classes.

```
columnWeightsPerRow   :  Table<Row, Column, Double> 
weightsPerRow         :  Map<Row, Double>
```

Here are 2 ways I have written so far, can you suggest better way which is more readable ?

This is first way I am writing code.

```
 Table<Row, Column, Double> applyWeights(Table<Row, Column, Double> columnWeightsPerRow,
      Map<Row, Double> weightsPerRow)
  {

    Table<Row, Column, Double> rowWeightedColumnWeights =
        HashBasedTable.create();

    columnWeightsPerRow
        .rowMap()
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .forEach( columnWeightsPerRowEntry -> columnWeightsPerRowEntry
                                                  .getValue().entrySet()
                                                  .forEach(weightPerColumn ->
                                                               rowWeightedColumnWeights.put(columnWeightsPerRowEntry.getKey(),
                                                                                                    weightPerColumn.getKey(),
                                                                                                    weightPerColumn.getValue() * weightsPerRow.get(columnWeightsPerRowEntry.getKey()))));
    return rowWeightedColumnWeights;

  }
```

This is second way of writing same code.

```
  Table<Row, Column, Double> applyWeights(Table<Row, Column, Double> columnWeightsPerRow,
      Map<Row, Double> weightsPerRow)
  {
    return columnWeightsPerRow
        .rowMap()
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(HashBasedTable::create,
                 (table, entry) ->
                     entry.getValue()
                                  .entrySet()
                                  .stream()
                                  .forEach(columnWeightEntry -> table.put(entry.getKey(),
                                                                         columnWeightEntry.getKey(),
                                                                         columnWeightEntry.getValue() * weightsPerRow.get(entry.getKey()))),
                 HashBasedTable::putAll);
  }
```

Comment: First, try to rewrite the first variant; instead of using `.entrySet() .stream() .forEach(entry -> ` or `.entrySet() .forEach(entry -> `, just use `forEach((key,value) -> ` and remove all these `getKey()` and `getValue()` calls. Then, compare again…

Comment: @Holger yes code looks much cleaner after this, I don’t think I can get better version.